# Flet dropdown asignar ruta

Tags: flet

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion movil con flet y quiero que una ves que se depliegue el menu dropdown poder hacer click en alguna de las alternativas y me lleve a otra ruta de la aplicacion.como podria?Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy comenzando con Flet, con lo cuál quizás no sea la mejor solución, yo uso [NavigationBar](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/navigationbar) en un main.py; importo vistas.py

```
from vistas import vista_login, vista_ppal, vista_informes, vista_usuarios
```

Con esto si tienes el archivo vistas.py en la misma carpeta main.py te cargará las funciones que llames en la importación y desde ahí me traigo las vistas para cada botón, haciendo un page.clean() para que no se acumulen.

```
    def cambiar_tab(e):
    #Indice de Tab
    mi_indice = e.control.selected_index
    page.clean()
    if mi_indice == 0:
        vista_ppal(page)
        page.navigation_bar.visible=True
    elif mi_indice == 1:
        vista_informes(page)
        page.navigation_bar.visible=True
    elif mi_indice == 2:
        vista_usuarios(page)
        page.navigation_bar.visible=True
    elif mi_indice == 3:
        page.dialog = dlg_modal
        dlg_modal.open = True
        page.update()

    
    page.update()
    

destinations = [
    ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.MAPS_HOME_WORK_OUTLINED, label="Principal"),
    ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.TABLE_CHART_OUTLINED, label="Informes"),
    ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.ATTACH_FILE_SHARP, label="Logout"),
]

if usuario_adm:
    destinations.insert(2, ft.NavigationDestination(icon=ft.icons.SUPERVISED_USER_CIRCLE_OUTLINED, label="Usuarios"))

page.navigation_bar = ft.NavigationBar(
    bgcolor=ft.colors.BLUE_GREY_700,

    selected_index=0,
    on_change=cambiar_tab,
    destinations=destinations,
    visible=True
)

if usuario_nom is not None:
    vista_ppal(page)
    page.navigation_bar.visible=True
else:
    page.navigation_bar.visible=False
    vista_login(page)
```

En este ejemplo, arranca con  la vista_login ocultando la barra de navegación y con el login exitoso ya carga la vista principal y habilitda la navegación.

Espero que te sirva y si hay soluciones mas eficientes siempre son bienvenidas.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).